# Grammar of the sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Is this sentence construction right?

> "You were intensively involved in doing a project or a research work during that semester, and hence was not focusing much in your course work"

Should the second part of the sentence have 'was' even though the subject is 'you'?

Comment: No. It should have _were_ since the subject is _you_. Why would anyone think it should have _was_?

Comment: This question smacks of lack of understanding of basic English. Need to be moved to the other forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which grammar rule allows you to place *was* with the pronoun *you?* You only wrote the first part of the sentence -*"**You were** intensively involved..."* and thus, it should be *maintained!*

So, to answer your question, it'd take the second person singular (past) *were*. Also, I'd prefer writing *...focus **on**...* and not *in.*

Answer (score 0):

No. *And hence **were***, not *was*. You need to keep the same verb tense.

Comment: It's not tense, it's *person* (2nd person singular).